# React: Alternatives to pushing methods up to parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I am working on a Rich Text Editor component using React and Draft.js that will be part of a library that my team uses to build our app's UI.  I'm running into problems organizing the component in order to separate state and functionality.  I'm not sure if it will matter to my questions, but we use Redux in our app but not in our library.

This is a version of the code that I have simplified to try to focus on the problems that I am having:

```
class TextInput extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      editorState: this.getInitialEditorState()
    };
    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
    this.toggleLinkMenu = this.toggleLinkMenu.bind(this);
    this.toggleInline = this.toggleInline.bind(this);
    this.toggleBlock = this.toggleBlock.bind(this);
  }

  onChange(editorState) {
    this.setState({ editorState });
  }

  toggleLinkMenu() {
    this.setState({ displayLinkTooltip: !this.state.displayLinkTooltip });
  }

  toggleInline(style) {
    this.setState({
      editorState: RichUtils.toggleInlineStyle(this.state.editorState, this.options.style)
    },
      this.editor.focus
    );
  }

  toggleBlock(blockType) {
    this.setState({
      editorState: RichUtils.toggleBlockType(this.state.editorState, this.options.blockType)
    },
      this.editor.focus
    );
  }

  render() {
    // While I'm developing, I have TextInput hardcoded to display every button in TextInputMenu:
    const buttonList = ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'hyperlink', 'headline', 'blockquote'];

    return (
      <div className={styles.textInput} >
        <TextInputMenu buttonList={buttonList} toggleInline={this.toggleInline} toggleBlock={this.toggleBlock} />
        <Editor  // This is the actual Draft.js Editor component where the user types their text
          ref={c => (this.editor = c)}
          editorState={this.props.editorState}
          onChange={this.props.onChange}
          placeholder={this.props.placeholder}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

// TextInputMenu */
// Contains a series of buttons that the user can click on to apply an inline
// style, apply a block style, or insert a hyperlink.
//
// The TextInput passes in a buttonList prop containing the names of the buttons
// that it wants to display.
class TextInputMenu extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.menuButtons = {
      bold: { name: 'Bold', icon: 'fa-bold', options: /* Options here */ },
      italic: { name: 'Italic', icon: 'fa-italic', options: /* Options here */ },
      underline: { name: 'Underline', icon: 'fa-underline', options: /* Options here */ },
      hyperlink: { name: 'Hyperlink', icon: 'fa-link', options: /* Options here */ },
      headline: { name: 'Headline', icon: 'fa-header', options: /* Options here */ },
      blockquote: { name: 'Block Quote', icon: 'fa-quote-left', options: /* Options here */ }
    };
  }

  getMenuButtons() {
    return _.pick(this.menuButtons, this.props.buttonList);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className={styles.textInputMenu}>
        {_.map(this.getMenuButtons(), ({name, icon, func}) => <TextInputMenuButton key={name} style={name} icon={icon} onClick={func} />)}
        {this.getMenuButtons().find('hyperlink') && <LinkMenu />}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const TextInputMenuButton = ({style, icon, onClick}) => (
  <div className={styles.textInputButton}>
    <i onClick={() => onClick(style)} className={`fa ${icon}`} />
  </div>
);

const LinkMenu = ({active, insertHyperlink}) => (
  <Tooltip active={active}>
    <form onSubmit={insertHyperlink}>
      <label>URL:</label>
      <input type="text" name="url" />

      <label>Displayed Text:</label>
      <input type="text" name="displayText" />

      <Button />
    </form>
  </Tooltip>
);

export { TextInput };
export default TextInput;
```

Generally, I avoid using refs; however, I need to call the Editor component's "focus" method. Is there a better way to call a child component's methods other than using a ref?

I'm locating editorState in TextInput since it is used by its child components.  However, this requires me to also locate methods that mutate editorState in TextInput even if locating them in a child component makes more sense.  For example, I would like to move the methods that handle the behavior of TextInputMenu's buttons (toggleLinkMenu, toggleInline, and toggleBlock) to the Menu itself since, as I add more buttons, it is becoming increasingly unwieldy to pass around configuration and handle PropTypes.  Is there some alternative pattern?  I know the React ecosystem tends to favor Functional programming techniques, but it almost seems like it would be better to take a page from Object Oriented programming and pass a setter function for editorState to the Menu.

Comment: You _could_ add a focus property, and then editor could then call `.focus` internally when the prop is changed. Otherwise what's wrong with using refs?

Answer (score 0):

`Is there a better way to call a child component's methods other than using a ref`

I don't know about *better*, but if you don't want to use a ref, then you can rerender the parent (using a setState, for instance) that will pass a prop to the child - e.g. lift the state up - that you can then use in the `componentDidUpdate` method of the child. Compare the previous props to the current props and, if the prop you passed is different, then call the method.

Answer (score 0):

Draft.js has a setter function like what you describe: `onChange`. You are passing it to the Draft.js `<Editor>`, and could pass it to `<TextInputMenu>` as well. This is a fairly common pattern when extending a Draft.js editor.

For your `focus` concern, if you haven't already read it have a look at the [official documentation](https://draftjs.org/docs/advanced-topics-managing-focus.html) which covers why it is managed imperatively.

Looking at your example, you might also solve this by bind the toolbar buttons with `onMouseDown` instead of `onClick` – this way, with `preventDefault()` on the event, there won't be a focus shift when clicking the buttons and you won't need to call `this.editor.focus()`. This is for example done in the [official rich text example](https://github.com/facebook/draft-js/blob/master/examples/draft-0-10-0/rich/rich.html#L152-L170):

```js
class StyleButton extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.onToggle = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      this.props.onToggle(this.props.style);
    };
  }
  render() {
    let className = 'RichEditor-styleButton';
    if (this.props.active) {
      className += ' RichEditor-activeButton';
    }
    return (
      <span className={className} onMouseDown={this.onToggle}>
        {this.props.label}
      </span>
    );
  }
}
```